# Excell VBA For Each Loop and Add Array cell adress

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, foreach

Can u help me please.
I have a one problem.

My VBA Code

```
Sub ercan()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sayfa1")

For Each gunadi In ws.Range("D1:AH1")
    If gunadi.Text = "CUMARTESİ" Then 'CUMARTESİ DAY NAME = Saturday
        gunadi.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        gunadi.Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    ElseIf gunadi.Text = "PAZAR" Then 'PAZAR DAY NAME = Sunday
        gunadi.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        gunadi.Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    Else
        gunadi.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        gunadi.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
Next

For Each haftaici In ws.Range("D4:AH4")
    If haftaici.Offset(-3, 0).Text = "PAZAR" Then
        MsgBox haftaici.Address(False, False)
        addr = haftaici.Address(False, False)             
    End If
    
    'afterrrrr do
    ws.Range("AK4").Value = "=" & addr
    
Next



End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvvnP.png)

I want select range -3 == pazar (Sunday) add array cell address and after used this string.

**H4 O4 V4 AC4 <= msgbox** . I need add array foreach loop

I WANT **=H4+O4+V4+AC4** THIS FORMAT DEBUG

I want to **collect Sundays** in **"AK4" cell** but value type =cell+cell+cell

how can i do i need your help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: you only need one loop.

```vb
Sub ercan()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, addr, sep
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sayfa1")
    
    For Each c In ws.Range("D1:AH1").Cells
        Select Case c.Text
            Case "CUMARTESI" 'Sat
                c.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
                c.Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
            Case "PAZAR" 'Sun
                c.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                c.Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                addr = addr & sep & c.Offset(3).Address(False, False) 'address from row 4
                sep = ","                                             'add comma after first sunday
            Case Else
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                c.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End Select
    Next
    
    If Len(addr) > 0 Then 'any Sundays?
        ws.Range("AK4").Formula = "=SUM(" & addr & ")"
    End If
End Sub
```